# How do I set Windows Server 2012 R2 to always prompt for login when connecting to it?

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, authentication, windows-authentication

I'm configuring Windows Server 2012 to replace my company's Linux Samba file server. When I connect to the server on a PC by clicking Network>Server, I need to set it to always require credentials before showing the shared folders. I think the server somehow stores the IP address for a PC after a user logs into it once (maybe only temporarily), so it doesn't require authentication when connecting.

I can see this being a problem because employees would worry it's not as secure as the previous Linux server.

Would someone be able to give me more information on where I specify this setting on the server, so everyone is prompted to login as soon as they try to connect? Thanks

Comment: Did you accidentally save your credentials and then forget about it?

Comment: Did you create an Active Directory domain?

Comment: @michaelHampton I didn't save credentials, because I've cleared with net use /delete command and also tried restarting. Still remembers folder I have on the drive without prompting for login

joeqwerty Yes, single domain controller with Active Directory

Comment: Also, PCs that haven't connected to it yet still prompt for login when I connect to it (without showing share folder beforehand).

Answer (score 0):

Check your share permissions and permissions on security tab on that share.

Maybe you have Guest account permitted to login.

Do you have Active Directory?

Comment: I checked permissions, the only group I'm sharing it to is domain users
Yes, I have AD

Comment: @Ellittle In AD, users are authenticated by logon credentials on their PCs. (Is this fileserver an AD member?). 

Make groups, add specific users to these groups.
On root share disable inheritance and then add permissions on specific folders. 
I don't think there is a way to enable prompting when server is AD member and AD users are logging into it.

Comment: What @ADPien said.  I suspect what you're seeing isn't "no credentials required" but instead normal single sign on behavior.

Comment: I'm not sure if the server is an AD member. I have disabled inheritance on the folder I'm sharing out, then specified the users and groups it should allow.
Ahhh, yeah @Katherine. I understand it doesn't need my credentials because I've logged in, I just didn't know what feature or setting was responsible for that. It must be set to single sign on, I'll try to find how to disable that, just so it's more like what they're used to. Thanks guys!

Comment: I'm still having trouble setting the authentication to not be single sign on. Every article is about enabling/configuring it, even though I'm looking to disable it or change the authentication. I'll continue to search, but let me know if you have any more information on how I can set the authentication to not remember credentials. Thanks